# Finding probability of drawing balls from a urn?

Tags: probability

A bag contains 5 red, 4 green and 3 black balls. Three balls are drawn out from it random. Find the probability of drawing exactly 2 red balls drawn?

I have no idea what to do i am getting no were trying it can anyone give a lead to me ?

Thanks

Akash

Comment: watttt??? u mean 2 balls of same colour?

Comment: sorry i missed a word it is 2 red balls i have editted it

Answer (score 1):

List all the cases  where exactly two balls of red color are drawn are RRG,RGR,GRR,BRR,RBR,RRB.

CASE RRG :- Probability = $\frac{5}{12}*\frac{4}{11}*\frac{4}{10}$

Do you know how to calculate this? If yes, then calculate the probability for all the cases seperately.

Then add the probabilities of all the cases.

Comment: aren't RRG and RGR the same because we are here talking about the cases in which we get 2 red balls but as you said you are also including the way in which the balls are picked , correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Nope they are not the same.They are two distinct events. I know you would be saying that we take out 3 balls at the same instant. but, that is just semantics. I had this doubt too. but this is how you do it. Refer some books for it(Arihant algebra is nice-IIT).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just do it for 3 cases...

1. Red, Red, Non-red
2. Red, Non-red, Red
3. Non-red, red, red